# MariaDB C library result fetch

Tags: c++, c, mariadb

I'm writing a simple SQL wrapper for my Application in C++ where I need to execute prepared statements with the MariaDB C API.

I'm not sure how to fetch the result which is not known to my library because it depends on the SQL query. All the examples rely on fixed result sets with maximum string lengths but that is not what I want when I bind the result set.

I need to iterate through all columns and get the type and the pointer to the underlying data. How is that possible with the C library? Are there any examples on how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know the size and types of columns in advance, you have to check the metadata which were sent by server after mysql_stmt_execute() first.

Execute the statement

```
if (mysql_stmt_execute(stmt))
  /* error handling */
```

Check if the statement returned a result set, get metadata and iterate over fields

```
if (mysql_stmt_field_count(stmt))
{
  MYSQL_FIELD *fields= mysql_stmt_fetch_fields(stmt);

  for (int i=0; i < mysql_stmt_field_count(stmt); i++)
  {
    switch (fields[i].type) {
      case MYSQL_TYPE_DOUBLE:
        ...
      case MYSQL_TYPE_LONGLONG:
        ...
    }
  }
}
```

The MYSQL_FIELD structure is described [here](https://github.com/mariadb-corporation/mariadb-connector-c/wiki/datastructures#mysql_field).
For examples you can also check the unittests of MariaDB Connector/C.

Comment: Thanks. I checked the unittests but they also use the same procedure. I don't understand how to set the result buffers for each individual row I need to fetch because they might change in size.

Comment: I did a little debugging on this and I got the field info but the length parameter gives the maximum possible size for example a LONGTEXT gives 4294967295 for the possible length which is not what I want because allocating that much memory even if there is no cell in the result which uses that amount of memory is ridiculous.

Answer (score 0):

i am no mysql expert.  it looks like The MYSQL_BIND structure is used to provide parameters for prepared statements or to receive output column values from prepared statements.

i think when you run a query the mysql interface pulls the data into its own memory space.  then you make another call to copy it into yours.  if you check the MYSQL_BIND structure after running the query, it has a buffer_length element that tells you what it got.  you should be able to size your receiver accordingly.